# Jquery form validation not working on a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, unobtrusive-validation

I have a ASP.NET MVC website and a page with a form.

I'm using jquery for the client side validation.

It's working fine with fields with [Required] attribute

But I have a field that is not required but must be an URL :

```
[Display(Name = "URL", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
[RegularExpression(@"^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "URL_WRONG_FORMAT")]
public string Url{ get; set; }
```

The validation is working when the format is not correct and my error message is displayed.

But when I send the form, I use

```
 $('#MyForm').submit(function() {
            var form = $(this);
            if (form.valid()) {...}
});
```

and the form is valid even with the field with the wrong format....

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

The valid method only validate visible fields. I had a form splited in 3 tabs and my field that I want to validate is not visible during the validation...